# Thread-safety: is making a data structure immutable enough?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety, immutability

I have a class that is accessed from different threads and which modifies the content of an array. I started with using a NSMutableArray but it was obviously not thread safe. Will it solve the thread safety problem to replace the NSMutableArray with a NSArray and make copies when needed?

For example:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSArray *_files;
}

- (void)removeFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    NSMutableArray *mutableFiles = [_files mutableCopy];
    [mutableFiles removeObject:fileName];
    _files = [mutableFiles copy];
}
```

instead of:

```
@implementation MyClass {
    NSMutableArray *_files;
}

- (void)removeFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    [_files removeObject:fileName];
}
```

Making copies is not so critical in my case since the array will stay pretty small and the remove operation won't be executed so often.

Comment: If you are really trying to archive a lock free thread safety, this Programmers SE post will be more appropriate: [Does immutability entirely eliminate the need for locks in multi-processor programming?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171253/does-immutability-entirely-eliminate-the-need-for-locks-in-multi-processor-progr) I heard awhile ago, 'immutable data storage AND single writer many readers' is possible. But yours doesn't look like 'single writer' access model. If I were you, I just use @synchronize(this) ;-)

Comment: It would be a rare situation (and maybe not possible on any of the platforms that Apple Objective-C can target), but in general you cannot assume that a pointer assignment is an atomic operation. It might actually take multiple processor instructions to write the whole thing, in which case a simultaneous reader thread has a chance of reading a garbage value that consists of part of the old pointer value and part of the new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it won't, you need to use @synchronized in your method to prevent multiple calls to removeFile: from being executed in parallel.

Like this:

```
- (void)removeFile:(NSString *)fileName {
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [_files removeObject:fileName];
    }
}
```

The reason it will not work with your code is that multiple threads calling removeFile: at the same time can cause this to occur:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFiles1 = [_files mutableCopy]; // Thread 1
[mutableFiles1 removeObject:fileName1];
// Thread 1 is interrupted, Thread 2 is run
NSMutableArray *mutableFiles2 = [_files mutableCopy]; // Thread 2
[mutableFiles2 removeObject:fileName2];
_files = [mutableFiles2 copy];
// Thread 1 is continued
_files = [mutableFiles1 copy];
```

At which point _files still contains `fileName2`

It is a race condition so it might look okay and work 99% of the time, but it is not *guaranteed* to be correct.

Comment: Now if I keep the immutable version, make it an atomic property, create no other lock, and if I don't care about the fact that the content of the array might sometimes be slightly wrong, can I be sure it won't crash?

Comment: It think it should work that way, if you can call the fact that your method sometimes does nothing "working". I wonder why you seem to think that using a lock is so bad ?

Answer (score 0):

No, that is insufficient to ensure thread-safety. You have to use one of the various [Synchronization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1) techniques outlines in the *Threading Programming Guide*, (e.g. using locks, such as `NSLock` or `@synchronized`).

Or, often more efficient, you can use a serial queue to synchronize the object (see *Eliminating Lock-Based Code* section of the [Migrating Away From Threads](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1) chapter of the *Concurrency Programming Guide*). While `@synchronized` is incredibly simple, I'd lean towards this latter approach of a dedicated serial queue to synchronize access:

```
// The private interface

@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray   *files;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t  fileQueue;

@end

// The implementation

@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _files = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _fileQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.domain.app.files", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)removeFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    dispatch_async(_fileQueue, ^{
        [_files removeObject:fileName];
    });
}

- (void)addFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    dispatch_async(_fileQueue, ^{
        [_files addObject:fileName];
    });
}

@end
```

The key in thread-safety is to ensure that all interaction with the object in question is synchronized. Simply using an immutable object is insufficient. And just wrapping `removeFile` in a `@synchronized` block is also insufficient. You generally want to synchronize *all* interaction with the object in question. You generally cannot just return the object in question and let the caller start using it without synchronizing its interaction. So, I might provide a method that allows the caller to interact with this `files` array in a thread-safe manner:

```
/** Perform some task using the files array
 *
 * @param block This is the block to be performed with the `files` array.
 *
 * @note        This block does not run on the main thread, so if you are doing any
 *              UI interaction, make sure to dispatch that back to the main queue.
 */
- (void)performMutableFileTaskWithBlock:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *files))block
{
    dispatch_sync(_fileQueue, ^{
        block(_files);
    });
}
```

You can then call that like so:

```
[myClassObject performMutableFileTaskWithBlock:^(NSMutableArray *files) {
    // do whatever you want with the files array here
}];
```

Personally, it gives me the willies to let the caller do whatever it wants with my array (I'd rather see `MyClass` provide an interface for whatever manipulation is needed). But if I need a thread-safe interface for the caller to access the array, I might prefer to see a block method like so, that provides a block interface with a deep copy of the array:

```
/** Perform some task using the files array
 *
 * @param block This is the block to be performed with an immutable deep copy of `files` array.
 */
- (void)performFileTaskWithBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *files))block
{
    dispatch_sync(_fileQueue, ^{
        NSArray *filesDeepCopy = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_files copyItems:YES]; // perform deep copy, albeit only a one-level deep copy
        block(filesDeepCopy);
    });
}
```

Going to your immutable question, the one thing you might do, though, is have a method that returns an immutable copy of the object in question, which you'll let the caller use as it sees fit, with an understanding that this represents the `files` array as a snapshot in time. (And, like above, you'd do a deep copy.)

```
/** Provide caller with a copy of the files array
 *
 * @return A deep copy of the files array.
 */
- (NSArray *)filesCopy
{
    NSArray __block *filesCopy;
    dispatch_async(_fileQueue, ^{
        filesCopy = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:_files copyItems:YES]; // perform deep copy
    });

    return filesCopy;
}
```

Clearly, though, this has limited practical usage. For example, where you're dealing with an array of file names, it might not be appropriate to return a immutable copy of that array if those file names correspond to actual physical files that might be manipulated by another thread. But in some cases, the above is a fine solution. It depends entirely upon the business rules of the model object in question.